# UDF Partition is readonly and has no size in windows but Read/Write in Linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, file-permissions, udf, ubuntu-17.04

I am having the following issue. I have an UDF partition for interoperability between Linux and windows on a dual boot system (having some VM hard disks images there). All was okay, I could read from and write to the partition on windows and Linux. But now I discovered that windows cannot write to the partition anymore because it sees it as read-only, Linux is still okay with it for writing.

Tried to unmount the partition in Linux and then reboot, did not make any difference, still not writable.

By the way I am using Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.04 with udftools.

Comment: Is this a dual-boot system, or a removable drive? If dual-boot, did you hibernate Linux when you booted Windows? Did you dismount the drive in Linux before switching? (I don't use UDF, but I've had similar problems with sharing other file systems.)

Comment: It is a dual boot system. I just shutdown linux... unmouting should be done automatically i guess while rebooting?

Comment: You could try dismounting manually to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: why don't just use NTFS or exFAT? or install ext drivers to Windows

Comment: No NTFS, has huge problems with user mapping in Linux. exFat could be used but this is what it is right now.

Comment: Dismounting did not work

Answer (score 2):

> But now I discovered that windows cannot write to the partition anymore because it sees it as read-only, Linux is still okay with it for writing.

This happen on Windows when UDF filesystem is in inconsistent state or damaged. Try to run chkdsk.exe and see if it reports some problems. Windows's chkdsk.exe supports checking for errors also on UDF filesystem. If there are really errors, you can try to fix them by specifying /F parameter... but I was told that chkdsk.exe /F in some cases when trying to repair broken UDF, damage it even more.

Comment: Tried this but no results. (maybe even more damage, as you were saying)

Comment: I haven't realized chkdsk support UDF. But it does! And it fixed the problem for my DVD-RW with UDF 2.5. Thanks!